# STM32F0, DRV8840 and GPIO Problems

Tags: dc, stm32, dc-motor, motordriver

Today I tested a DC driver with a STM32 MCU. The schematic is like this:

[image]

I have a problem with the ENABLE Signal between the DRV8840 and the MCU.

When the DC Motor is disconnected, I toggle the EN pin and I can see +12V and -12V alternatively on the out pins of the DRV8840. Everything is OK.

When the DC Motor is connected. The MCU init is OK. When I set the EN Signal, the motor runs. But when I ask to toggle the EN Signal, it keeps 3.3V and the motor can't stop.

I can't toggle the EN Pin when the motor is running. WHY?

I don't understand why. My GPIO Pin is configured as Push Pull Output.

Comment: Can you verify that your code is still running when the failure occurs? Try connecting your SWD and see if some kind of fault has occurred.

Comment: Yes my code is still running without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have the answer...

It was due to encoder interrupts. My motor is coupled with an encoder and when I disconnect the motor, I also disconnect the encoder. I tested my program with disabling the interrupt and it is ok.